# htaccess directory listing

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to list files in one particular directory and with one particular ip. This htaccess file is located in that directory. So far, it seems that the hosting does not allow me to list directories. On localhost i can list everything in that directory, except the IndexIgnore ones, of course. The htaccess file content is:

```
Options +Indexes

<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 1.1.1.1
</Limit>

IndexIgnore tabele_remote.php
IndexIgnore demo.txt
IndexIgnore functions.php
IndexIgnore config.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that AllowOverride directive is set somewhere previously

Also check there is no IndexIgnore * set on the parent directories or server entirely

Comment: It tries to list the directory, but there are no files. imageshack.us/f/857/capture1qv.jpg

Answer (score 0):

change `order deny,allow` to `order allow,deny` and give it a try.

Also set `AllowOverride all`

Comment: It tries to list the directory, but there are no files. http://imageshack.us/f/857/capture1qv.jpg/

Comment: You have files in that directory?

Comment: May be they are also added to IndexIgnore somewhere previously, i.e. something like this IndexIgnore *.php  ?

Comment: How do i remove the previously declared IndexIgnore *.php?

Comment: IMHO there is only one way to fix impact of the indexignore directive, i.e. not to use it in a way like IndexIgnore *. Instead it is properly to use Options -Indexes. So you must either to change that yourself or contact server admin, if you disclosed that this is exactly your case. But I can not be sure 100%, that is not my realm

Comment: i have deleted the directive from the main .htaccess. Thanks!